# SwiftUI Mac OS DatePicker jumps back to day on edit

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using a DatePicker in SwiftUI on MacOS. Whenever I make a changes to the month or year, the date picker selection jumps back to the day. That is quiet annoying when you change the month, it will jump back to the day.

That is the code I am using for the DatePicker:

```
DatePicker(
  selection: $s_selectedDate,
  displayedComponents: .date,
  label: { EmptyView() }
).padding(.horizontal, 20)
```

I have recorded a video to demonstrate the issue:
[image]
Issue in the Video: When I am typing 4 in the month, it jumps instant back to the day
Is that an issue I am able to solve or is it intentionally? Apple is not using that Picker in contact books. Not sure where to find it though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like internal issue. You can submit feedback to Apple anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed now in Xcode 11.4. Furthermore, they have added the graphical calendar by default.

[image]

Comment: In Xcode 11.6 it's still broken for `displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute`.